# How to implement javascript into php file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have this code and i want to implement the java script below into this php code, I need to excute javascript even this php called from index.php
any help please

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

        $('.estudent_id').click(function(){
            $student_id = $(this).attr('name');
            $('#edit_query').load('load_edit1.php?student_id=' + $student_id);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Check_data.php**

```
<table id = "table" class = "table table-bordered">

<?php
$dtpickerdate = isset($_POST['dtpickerdate']) ? $_POST['dtpickerdate'] : NULL;

 $q_customer = $conn->query
                             ("SELECT * from orders inner JOIN customer_order on customer_order.order_no =orders.order_no and orders.date like'$dtpickerdate' inner join driver_order  on driver_order.order_no=orders.order_no LEFT JOIN customer on customer.phone=customer_order.phone order by k_time,time desc" )
 or die(mysqli_error());

 $k_time = '';
 while($f_customer = $q_customer->fetch_array()){
 $s=mysqli_num_rows($q_customer);
 ?>
  <tr>
 <?php   

    if($k_time == '' || $k_time != $f_customer['k_time']){
     $k_time = $f_customer['k_time'];
     echo '<td align="center" > <span style=" font-weight:bold;">' 
     .$f_customer['k_time']. '</td>';
      } else{
      echo "<td td style=' border: none;'>&nbsp;</td>";
      }
       echo "<td style='background-color: #5f5d5d; ' align='center'  span style='font-weight:bold;'> <a   href = '#' style='color:#ececec;font-weight:bold;' data-toggle = 'modal' data-target = '#action'>".$f_customer['order_no']."</a></td>";

   echo    "<td style='background-color: #5f5d5d;color:#ececec;'>" .$f_customer['first_name']."</td>"; 
  echo "<td style='background-color: #5f5d5d;color:#ececec;'>". 
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please rephrase it and mention what's your goal is.

Comment: you mean this page `check_data.php` will be included in your `index.php` file ? right ?

Comment: @Usman Rana  i have index.php which only have datepicker and this datepicker calls another page (check_data.php) now in check_data i need to excute some javascript codes but i dont know why they didnt work, they only works on index.php

Answer (score 1):

Just add script outside php as you do in html.
For Ex. in your code put something like this .
This might be helpful...

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $('.estudent_id').click(function(){
         $student_id = $(this).attr('name');
         $('#edit_query').load('load_edit1.php?student_id=' + $student_id);
    });
</script>
<table id = "table" class = "table table-bordered">
<?php
$dtpickerdate = isset($_POST['dtpickerdate']) ? $_POST['dtpickerdate'] : NULL;

 $q_customer = $conn->query
                             ("SELECT * from orders inner JOIN customer_order on customer_order.order_no =orders.order_no and orders.date like'$dtpickerdate' inner join driver_order  on driver_order.order_no=orders.order_no LEFT JOIN customer on customer.phone=customer_order.phone order by k_time,time desc" )
 or die(mysqli_error());

 $k_time = '';
 while($f_customer = $q_customer->fetch_array()){
 $s=mysqli_num_rows($q_customer);
 ?>
  <tr>
 <?php   

    if($k_time == '' || $k_time != $f_customer['k_time']){
     $k_time = $f_customer['k_time'];
     echo '<td align="center" > <span style=" font-weight:bold;">' 
     .$f_customer['k_time']. '</td>';
      } else{
      echo "<td td style=' border: none;'>&nbsp;</td>";
      }
       echo "<td style='background-color: #5f5d5d; ' align='center'  span style='font-weight:bold;'> <a   href = '#' style='color:#ececec;font-weight:bold;' data-toggle = 'modal' data-target = '#action'>".$f_customer['order_no']."</a></td>";

   echo    "<td style='background-color: #5f5d5d;color:#ececec;'>" .$f_customer['first_name']."</td>"; 
  echo "<td style='background-color: #5f5d5d;color:#ececec;'>". 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Echoing the javascript at the right place in your PHP file(s) should work:

```
<?php echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'>$('.estudent_id').click(function(){$student_id = $(this).attr('name');$('#edit_query').load('load_edit1.php?student_id=' + $student_id);});</script>"; ?>
```

If you want this javascript in multiple files, you could save the contents above as a PHP file, for example myscript.php and then include it in every file where you want the code to appear and run using this:

```
<?php include('myscript.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in...

Comment: Your JS code had an error which I didn't check:  an extra )}; right before the closing script tag.  I updated my answer to remove it.  Try it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can echo the JS like:

```
<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$('.estudent_id').click(function()     {$student_id = $(this).attr('name');$('#edit_query').load('load_edit1.php?student_id=' + $student_id);});});</script>"; ?>
```

Comment: but what about this error
unexpected '=', expecting

Comment: no its not working because page not appear in browser.. page contains javascript is called by script in index so that doesn't excute javascript

Comment: <?php echo"<script language='javascript'><?php echo $('.estudent_id').click(function(){$student_id = $(this).attr('name');$('#edit_query').load('load_edit1.php?student_id=' + $student_id);});</script>"; ?>